# What does it exactly mean to say the IoT Protocols are not standardized?

Tags: standards

It is said that there is no standard for IoT Protocol Communication. What does it mean to say that?

Comment: Hey, could you source your first sentence?  It might help to have some context.  Thanks!

Comment: You should clarify your question, because I interpret it multiple ways. For example, is your question: Is there one (or more) standard protocol(s) for IoT communication? Or perhaps you meant: Of the possible protocols (e.g., MQTT) that I would use for IoT, are they standardized?

Comment: This is not necessarily a bad question, but some more context or detail will help. As it is written, this looks just like a homework question (where you're expected to repeat the couple of paragraphs you were taught, and everyone knows are an inaccurate simplification). Knowing why you care will make it much easier for people to answer. Are you designing, buying or selling a product, a consumer, or a passer-by intrigued by a paradox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you mean to say is, the on field M2M communication protocols are not standardised for e.g, some devices use zigbee, some use zwave some use ble etc.

So in a premises when you have multiple devices from multiple vendors all implementing different protocols like the ones mentioned above, it becomes a problem to fetch the data from all these devices as you need a middle layer/device which would support all these different protocols fetch the data and push it forward. So there is no single communication protocol used by all manufacturers. This is what people mean typically when they say there is no standardization of protocols for IOT.

Protocols like MQTT and CoAP are typically used for exchange of data between a field gateway and a remote server (like the azure iot hub).

Hope it made sense.

Answer (score 3):

The premise of your question is flawed, things like [MQTT](http://mqtt.org/2014/11/mqtt-v3-1-1-now-an-oasis-standard) and [COaP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7252) are standards.

Comment: yes, there's mqtt, but that's not the whole story. consider http without html; servers can talk to browsers, but the browser wouldn't know what it was saying... There's no spec for what message a temperature should be transmitted as; the field names, the number type, the range of acceptable values, etc; each mqtt install is an island of proprietary naming conventions and data encoding.

Comment: @dandavis well said, and with all these variations probably the best way to go about, is to introduce data definition guidelines which the transmitter and receiver can adhere to along with some configuration setting tools that help the user to define their data as per the set guidelines. More often than not this will have to be incorporated within the application software than in the firmware within the hardware